# Switch between Tabs in TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to make an app, which has a NavigationController and a TabBarController as its root view. One Tab has no tabbar at the bottom of the screen. So I want to switch programmatically to the tab before, when I leave the view. I tried it with tabBarController.selectedIndex, but when the tab at the index appears, the tabbar item on the top of the screen is missing. 
How can I fix it?

Here is the code snippet ("previous view" is a bool which changes, when a tabview appears):

```
func goToPreviousView(button: UIButton!) {

        if previousView == 0 {
            tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
        }
        if previousView == 2 {
            tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
        }
        if previousView == 3 {
            tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 3
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you post your code and refer to 1-2 links you saw from SO, but weren't helpful?

Comment: okay, hope this code is helpful..